# CUDA 7.5 Visual Studio 2013 crash

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio-2013, cuda, crash

I'm trying to get CUDA up and running with Visual Studio 2013 professional. I have a MSI notebook with a GTX765M and when I start a new CUDA project in Visual Studio several things happen.

When I build the project everything seems to work fine. Whenever I click build and run, Visual Studio crashes. Sometimes I get the following notification: a 64-bit debugging operation is taking longer than expected.

Also, when I build the project and open the created .exe file, my explorer.exe freezes and nothing happens further. How does this come?

Hope someone can help me getting everything up and running.

Ohh by the way, I also have visual studio 2015 installed on the same machine which doesn't have CUDA toolkit installed, it's only installed on the 2013 one. It's all running on Windows 10

Comment: Realistically, the only person who can fix this sort of problem is the person sitting in front of the machine, i.e. you. You best bet is to simply uninstall everything and then follow the installation instructions for the platform and CUDA version you are using *exactly*, If it doesn't work, make a bug report to to NVIDIA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After hours and hours of struggling, debugging, uninstalling CUDA over three times, installing Visual Studio again, I figured out that it had to do with my virus scanner..... I disabled Avast Antivirus and everything worked as supposed. I still wonder why this happened, but I hope this answer will help others with this problem too!